# How should I seed data in Entity Framework 6

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-6, entity-framework-migrations, seed

I've problem with seeding data to database. Eariler I tried way from this tut: [Seed Data in EF 6 Code-First](https://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/code-first/seed-database-in-code-first.aspx)
and then the seed method is never called

**DBSchool.cs**

```
namespace SchoolTest.DAL
{
    public class DBSchool : DbContext
    {
        public DBSchool() : base("DBSchool")
        {
            Database.SetInitializer(new Seeder());
        }
        protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {
            modelBuilder.Conventions.Remove<PluralizingTableNameConvention>();
        }

        public DbSet<Guest> Guests { get; set; }
    }
}
```

**Seeder.cs**

```
public class Seeder : DropCreateDatabaseAlways<DBSchool>
    {
        protected override void Seed(DBSchool context)
        {
            IList<Guest> GuestList = new List<Guest>();
            GuestList.Add(new Guest()
            {
                Name = "Dexter",
                Surname = "Dexter",
                Email = "test@test.com"
            });

            context.Guests.AddRange(GuestList);
            context.SaveChanges();
            base.Seed(context);
        }
    }
```

**Guest.cs**

```
public class Guest
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string Surname { get; set; }
        public string Email { get; set; }
        [Key]
        public int GuestId { get; set; }
    }
```

**App.config**

```
  <appSettings>
    <add key="DatabaseInitializerForType SchoolTest.DAL.DBSchool, SchoolTest"
        value="SchoolTest.Data.Seeder, SchoolTest" />
  </appSettings>
```

Is there any way to call the Seed() method or just through the Configuration.cs?

Answer (score 0):

Try changing your code like this.

```
public class DBSchool : DbContext
{
    public DBSchool() : base("name=<database-name>")
    {
        Database.SetInitializer<DBSchool>(new Seeder());
    }

    // Rest of your implementation
}
```

Replace `<database-name>` with the name of your database.

**If** that didn't work, you can give a Generic Type Parameter to the context class and change your code as follows.

**Seeder.cs** -> `public class Seeder<T> : DropCreateDatabaseAlways<DBSchool>`

**DBSchool.cs** -> `Database.SetInitializer<DBSchool>(new Seeder<DBSchool>());`

Read more on that [here](https://www.codeguru.com/csharp/article.php/c19999/Understanding-Database-Initializers-in-Entity-Framework-Code-First.htm).

**If** that didn't work either, you can use migrations and seed data using [custom sql](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/ef6/modeling/code-first/migrations/#data-motion--custom-sql) using `Sql()`.